# Unix: Getting Export PATH to "Stick"

Tags: unix, shell, path, terminal, export

When setting the export path in Unix, example:

```
export PATH=$PATH: $EC2_HOME/bin
```

If I quit terminal and open it back up to continue working, I have to go through all the steps again, setting up the paths each time.
I'm wondering how I can set the path and have it "stick" so my system knows where to find everything the next time I open terminal without having to do it all over again.
Thanks!

Comment: Don't include the space between the colon and $EC2_HOME.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open `~/.bashrc.` This file is loaded every time you start up a new shell (if you're using Bash, which most people are). If you're using a different shell, the file may have a different name, like `~/.shrc`.

Add the line you need to the bottom of the file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bi
```

Other info rolled up from elsewhere in the thread:

There are multiple places to put this, depending on your shell and your needs. All of these files are in your home directory:

For Bash:

```
.bashrc (executed when you shart a shell)
```

OR

```
.bash_profile (executed when you log in)
```

For csh and tcsh:

```
.cshrc
```

For sh and ksh:

```
.profile
```

Comment: Generally, you are better off doing this in a profile file - executed once when you login, rather than in an rc file (like .bashrc) which is read whenever you start a shell.

Comment: Important safety tip: Put quotes around variable expansions, e.g., `export PATH="$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bi"` (unless you’re using a shell like zsh, which treats them as quoted by default to avoid these kinds of mistakes).

Answer (score 2):

Add it to your  .cshrc file (for csh and tcsh), .profile file (for sh and ksh), or .bash_profile file (for bash)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find your profile file and put that line in there. Suppose you use bash, the profile files are .bashrc and .bash_profile, found in ~. These files will vary depending on which shell you use.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put those commands into one of the "autostart" files of your shell.

For bash this would be `.bashrc` in your homedirectory (create it if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

add it to your .bashrc or another .bash startup file.

Answer (score 0):

... and for ksh edit **.profile**.