# arm-none-eabi commands will not install correctly

Tags: linux, makefile, raspberry-pi

I'm attempting to install a toolchain for assembly code on the raspberry pi. I used the following procedure to install the package files:

```
$ wget http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/downloads/arm-none-eabi.tar.bz2
--2012-08-16 18:26:29--  http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/downloads/arm-none-eabi.tar.bz2
Resolving www.cl.cam.ac.uk (www.cl.cam.ac.uk)... 128.232.0.20, 2001:630:212:267::80:14
Connecting to www.cl.cam.ac.uk (www.cl.cam.ac.uk)|128.232.0.20|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 32108070 (31M) [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: `arm-none-eabi.tar.bz2'

100%[======================================>] 32,108,070   668K/s   in 67s

2012-08-16 18:27:39 (467 KB/s) - `arm-none-eabi.tar.bz2' saved [32108070/32108070]

$ tar xjvf arm-none-eabi.tar.bz2
arm-2008q3/arm-none-eabi/
arm-2008q3/arm-none-eabi/lib/
arm-2008q3/arm-none-eabi/lib/libsupc++.a
arm-2008q3/arm-none-eabi/lib/libcs3arm.a
...
arm-2008q3/share/doc/arm-arm-none-eabi/info/gprof.info
arm-2008q3/share/doc/arm-arm-none-eabi/info/cppinternals.info
arm-2008q3/share/doc/arm-arm-none-eabi/LICENSE.txt

$ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/arm-2008q3/bin
```

That appeared to work, the package files are in the correct place.

```
 ~/arm-2008q3/bin $ ls
arm-none-eabi-addr2line  arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.3.2  arm-none-eabi-objdump
arm-none-eabi-ar         arm-none-eabi-gcov       arm-none-eabi-ranlib
arm-none-eabi-as         arm-none-eabi-gdb        arm-none-eabi-readelf
arm-none-eabi-c++        arm-none-eabi-gdbtui     arm-none-eabi-run
arm-none-eabi-c++filt    arm-none-eabi-gprof      arm-none-eabi-size
arm-none-eabi-cpp        arm-none-eabi-ld         arm-none-eabi-sprite
arm-none-eabi-g++        arm-none-eabi-nm         arm-none-eabi-strings
arm-none-eabi-gcc        arm-none-eabi-objcopy    arm-none-eabi-strip
```

However, when I go to make, I get the following outcome.

```
arm-none-eabi-as -I source/ source/main.s -o build/main.o
make: arm-none-eabi-as: Command not found
make: *** [build/main.o] Error 127
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can you give the output of echo $PATH

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/uuqv/.rvm/bin:/home/uuqv/arm-2008q3/bin`
Also, 
`uuqv@Theta ~ $ which arm-none-eabi-as
/home/uuqv/arm-2008q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-as`

Comment: I tried making it on the pi itself and I got a new error message:

`make  
arm-none-eabi-as -I source/ source/main.s -o build/main.o
/home/pi/arm-2008q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-as: 1: /home/pi/arm-2008q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-as: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make: *** [build/main.o] Error 2`

Comment: what happens if you try to manually run that command that fails? arm-none-eabi-as -I source/ source/main.s -o build/main.o

Comment: @UuqV Did you find any solution?!

Answer (score 2):

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/arm-2008q3/bin is only valid in the shell it is executed in (and any shells spawned from that shell). So you either use that shell instead of opening a new one to execute make or edit your ~/.bashrc (see [Unix: Getting Export PATH to "Stick"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209145/unix-getting-export-path-to-stick))

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and in my case the problem was that I was running a 64-bit operating system and the package to be used is a 32-bit. The fix was to install i32-libs package which allows running 32-bit applications on a 64-bit system.

```
# apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: I am in this same situation, but ia32-libs is no longer available!  What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You have to direct your compiler to the right path where `arm-none-eabi-as` is located. You can do so by

> export PATH=$PATH:/file_path_goes_here/

When you compile, you should have no problems as the compiler will now know where to look.